How can i Add Custom Controll to devexpress ribbonControl
i have made a controll contain 2 devexpress dateEdit fields for my own tools
how can i add this control to devexpress ribbon control
any idea
i try alot o method with no result
How to register a custom editor for use
looking in Custom Editors
RepositoryItemAnyControl Class but i can't find a clear sample
